What is the difference between fair secret sharing and verifiable secret sharing?
FSS
A secret sharing scheme called fairness requires the following conditions:

When there are no attackers, all participants can reconstruct secrets;
In the presence of external attackers, honest participants can reconstruct secrets.
Secret and external attackers cannot reconstruct the secret;
When there are insider attackers, honest participants and insider attacks
Either all people restore the secret, or none of them can restore the secret, that is, internal
Attackers cannot gain more advantage than honest people.

VSS
Verifiable secret sharing requires verification in two aspects:

Participants verify shares provided by secret distributors
Participants verify the shares exchanged with each other

I think there should be no difference between the two.

These are different properties:
Fair Secret Sharing
Corrupted parties can receive their outputs if and only if the honest parties also receive their outputs.
Verifiable Secret Sharing

Inconsistent or incorrect shares sent by dealer to participants during the distribution protocol must be detected.

Participants submitting incorrect shares during the reconstruction protocol must be detected.


Difference
Suppose we have a Verifiable Secret Sharing Scheme. Although our scheme can be used to check the validity of shares, It cannot prevent
the adversary from exclusively obtaining the secret since shares are revealed to participants in the reconstruction phase.
In an asynchronous secret reconstruction; when all other shareholders honestly release their shares, a dishonest shareholder can always exclusively recover the secret by presenting a fake share last. Thus, the other honest shareholders get nothing but false output. Although this behavior is detected, adversary obtains the correct output unfairly. In this case, the scheme is verifiable but not fair.

Thank you for solving my doubts.
